# USB enumeration failing in WIN 10

Tags: usb

I have USB 1.1 Full Speed CDC Class USB device when I connect this device to WIN 7/WIN 8 the USB enumeration is completed and I can install the drivers.

But when I connect this to a WIN 10 Host the device is not enumerating. Connected USB analyzer to WIN 7 and WIN 10 I found that there is timeout in case of WIN 10 during the enumeration process.

Do we have any setting in WIN 10 so that this time-out can be avoid and it behaves similar to WIN 7 and WIN 8?